# MSSQL updating rows using MSSQL Server Management Studio UPDATE statement fails inserting UTF8 characters

Tags: sql-server

Please note I am able to correctly update each row by manually typing each chinese, arabic, russian.. value.

But altering same row using a simple UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE ISO_Languages
SET 
name_fr = 'Chinois', 
name_it = 'Cinese',
name_es = 'Chino',
name_de = 'Chinesisch', 
name_zh = '中文',
name_ru = 'Китайский',
name_ar = 'صينى',
IsEnabled = 1
WHERE code = 'zh-CN';
```

does not update name_zh, name_ru, name:ar columns

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `nvarchar` preface your unicode string literals with an uppercase `N`. e.g.`N'中文'`

Make sure your column data type is `nvarchar` for unicode characters.

```
UPDATE ISO_Languages
SET 
name_fr = N'Chinois', 
name_it = N'Cinese',
name_es = N'Chino',
name_de = N'Chinesisch', 
name_zh = N'中文',
name_ru = N'Китайский',
name_ar = N'صينى',
IsEnabled = 1
WHERE code = 'zh-CN';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE ISO_Languages
SET 
name_fr = N'Chinois', 
name_it = N'Cinese',
name_es = N'Chino',
name_de = N'Chinesisch', 
name_zh = N'中文',
name_ru = N'Китайский',
name_ar = N'صينى',
IsEnabled = 1
WHERE code = 'zh-CN';
```